# Setting values in nested dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have nested dict like:

```
tdict = {folder': {'file0.txt': 222, 'subfolder': {'file1.txt': 333}}, 'file00.txt': 111}
```

and it can go deeper

How to iterate throw existing dict and add for ex. new item `'file2'`, described by list:

```
path_list = ['folder', 'subfolder', 'file2']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function will add a file if `value` isn't `None`, but will add a new directory otherwise:

```
def add_path(parent, path, value=None):
    end = len(path) - 1
    for index, component in enumerate(path):
        if index < end or value is None:
            parent = parent.setdefault(component, {})
        else:
            parent[component] = value
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to keep the dictionary structure. So, what you want to do is iterate through the list:

```
currItem = tdict
for item in path_list:
    if item not in currItem:
        currItem[item] = value
    else:
        currItem = currItem[item]
```

Depending on how you want to define your input list 'syntax' you will need to decide what to put in the `value` variable.